# PHP / Mysql increment by one from previous row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to take the ID that auto increments already from the latest row in a table and increment it by one and append it on to a returned result from that same table. So if the row id is 5 and the tabledata result is product5, I need it changed to product6 in the php result. So when the data is resubmitted it is in-line with the new row ID.

EDIT: 
I need it displayed and incremented before the sql insert because it's also emailed on data submit for ordering. The database insert is just to retain the order record.

Current code display results:

```
$conn=mysql_connect(" "," "," ");
mysql_select_db("database",$conn);
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=(SELECT max(ID) FROM table)";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

echo '<table>
<tr>
<td>Data: '.$result["tabledata"].'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Why not use mysql built-in `autoincrement`?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea

Comment: "I am looking to take the ID from the latest row in a table and increment it by one": **why**? You look like you have a *different* problem and believe you can solve it with incrementing. You may well be right, at that! But if you told us what the *originating problem* is, you could get a more useful answer.

Comment: This is ESPECIALLY a bad idea if you have to deal with any level of concurrency.

Comment: @cale_b because the ID is already set to autoincrement which i am taking the last row and pretty much using all the same data except one field, which needs to increment by one before it's added back in to sql

Comment: @lserni it's from a simple HTML form submit but i have the data being pushed to SQL before it sends the form mail. Then i am using the sql data to recall the orders for reorder only thing that needs to change is a Purchase order field so it stays in line with the previous just one number different (Example PO-01 to PO-02)

Answer (score 1):

What if you modify the query to select value after incrementing it. i.e.

```
SELECT ID+1 AS ID, /*all other fields of the table */ FROM table WHERE ID=(SELECT max(ID) FROM table)
```

Comment: @Iserni Look at the where clause .. he is only getting the max(ID) so this will work.

Comment: I see. But then isn't it what he's already doing? You just outsource the increment to MySQL instead of doing it in PHP.

Comment: @Iserni - He is not able to increment it as you can see in the code. He is just trying to display the result set. This can be incremented at either PHP/Mysql. If you argue whats the best approach, well at the first place increment the result is bad idea.

Comment: the issue is i need it displayed before sql can increment it because it's also submitted via email for ordering i know this is not the best way to do things but it's what needs to be done now

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand, you have *two* fields, not one:

```
id    tabledata
1     PO-01
5     product5
```

> is a Purchase order field so it stays in line with the previous just one number different (Example PO-01 to PO-02)

First thing that comes to mind is *not* to write that number in two places anyway. You could have

```
id    tabledata
1     PO-%02d
5     product%d
```

and then wherever you had the row data, you could use

```
sprintf($row['tabledata'], $row['id'])
```

to get the "human readable" version of `tabledata`. Then to get the "next" ID you could just do

```
sprintf($row['tabledata'], $row['id'] + 1)
```

Otherwise, you need to *extract the number from the text field*. This requires that you **know in advance its format** (e.g. is it %d or %02d or...?).

If you know it is just the number, with variable length, as in your first example (product5 to product6), you do

```
$table['tabledata'] = preg_replace('#\\d+$#', $table['id'] + 1);
```

The above will replace the last sequence of numeric digits (here, 5; it could be 1701 for example) with 6. Or you can capture the number with `preg_match` and much the same expression, only in parentheses, increment it, and store it back.

If it is a fixed-length sequence of numbers as in your second example (PO-01 to PO-02), you just use `substr`:

```
$size = 2; // Two-digit number

$num  = substr($table['tabledata'], -$size);
$prd  = substr($table['tabledata'], 0, -$size);

$table['tabledata'] = $prd . sprintf("%0{$size}d", $num + 1);
```

An even more complicated solution would be to merge the two versions into a "decoding" function that would count leading zeroes and digit lengths and use this to determine the format being used. This however would have problems in some cases (e.g. maybe the next number out from AB-99 is not AB-100 but AC-00 or AC-01), so all in all I think this is best left to someone with the knowledge of the specific domain.